# Cluster Markers from MapsEngineLayer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am creating a Google maps API.. I am getting the markers from Maps Engine and it showing just fine. I want to cluster the markers in a certain zoom level but I'm having trouble doing it.

This is how I create and add the layers.

```
var mapsEngineLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
    mapId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    layerKey: 'layer_00002',
    map: map,
    clickable: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: false
});
```

I tried to do this on clustering

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map);
```

I am wondering I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how are you adding markers to this cluster?? A cluster cannot work without markers. What MapsEngineLayer returns is an image and not a marker object

Comment: @jsjunkie, That make sense.. :) do you have any suggestion on how to "cluster" this?

Comment: I think it's not possible with MapsEngine. You will have to create marker objects manually in javascript and for that you require to have the coordinates. You can store the coordinates in external databases. I would also like to mention that fetching data from mapsengine layer is very costly in terms of their API usage limit(if you are using private map loads).